# How do I concatenate two vectors with one line of code

Tags: c++, stdvector

I swear this is not a duplicate of any of the seemingly-endless number of threads on vector concatenation.  For my case, in a derived class constructor I need to pass a `std::vector<int>` to the base class constructor, but the passed vector needs to be a concatenation of two other vectors.  Example:

```
#include <vector>    
using namespace std;

struct Base {
    Base(vector<int> numbers) {
        //Do something with numbers
    }
};

struct Derived: public Base {
    Derived(vector<int> numbers):
        Base(concatenate(numbers, {4,5,6})) {}  //Is there a built-in "concatenate" function?
}; 

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Derived D({1,2,3});
    return 0;
}
```

I can obviously do this by writing my own `concatenate` function, but I'm wondering if there is already a standard-library way to do this.  None of the examples of vector concatenation I've found are suitable to use in an initialization list because they span multiple lines; I need a one-liner concatenation.

Comment: A lambda, perhaps? Really, a function would be better.

Comment: I think the reason why you haven't found such a way that there is currently no such way in the standard library. Consider writing your own function: it doesn't require that many lines of code.

Comment: void insert (iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last); is this not good enough ?

Comment: We have the same problem in java.  What you want doesn't exist simply because the language was defined before these containers.  We're stuck using elaborate methods to get away from primitives.

Comment: @Carlton I do not see two vectors in the classes that you are going to concatenate. So it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Philip Stuyck: I don't think this is good enough for the specified use case: the original poster still has to write the concatenate function.

Comment: There is none - write your own

Comment: @VladfromMoscow There are two vectors in the call to the Base class constructor: one is the vector that was passed to the derived class constructor and the other is a temporary vector created on-the-fly.

Comment: How hard is it to write one line of insert/emplace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK since `numbers` is passed by value we can use trickery by combining the initializer list `insert` with the comma operator:

```
struct Derived: public Base {
    Derived(vector<int> numbers):
        Base((numbers.insert(numbers.end(), {4,5,6}), numbers)) {}
};
```

Comment: That *is* some trickery.  I've always looked down upon the comma operator but in this case it might be the best solution.  In my actual code the vectors are passed by r-value reference.  I tested your method and it seems to work with the r-values as well.

Answer (score 3):

To add a vector [b] to a vector [a]:

```
    a.insert(a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
```

If you don't want to alter a you can just copy it to a third vector.

Comment: Oh, so it is.  Sorry, I didn't check.  I'm kind of new to this community.

Comment: gotta love the verbosity of the standard library, it could have been as simple as a += b

Comment: So how would I use this in my example?  `std::vector::insert` returns an iterator, whereas my base class constructor needs a vector.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Then why didn't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Carlton Consider changing your class to take iterators. Then someone can create it with a subset of a vector without needing to change it.

Comment: @Neil because you don't post an answer if you are not sure if it is in fact the answer. I have had downvotes just for mentioning 'I think this might be the answer' and for the remainder posting a perfectly legitimate answer, just like this would have been.

Comment: You didn't say "I think this is the answer", you said "is this not good enough ?". Not the same thing.

Comment: @Neil I don't agree obviously ;-) being careful was not a good idea in this case. Not the end of the world.